# Trying to handle the error thrown by mkdir

Tags: node.js

Evening, beginner here.

Im trying to make the MKCOL method for a small server i made locally that uses the fs.mkdir method to create the directory, it runs the way i want when i make it create a directory that doesn't exist, but when the directory exists, it throws an error in the server that i tried to handle but couldn't, this is the server and the functions that my MKCOL method uses:

```
const {createServer} = require("http");

const methods = Object.create(null);

createServer((request, response) => {
  let handler = methods[request.method] || notAllowed;
  handler(request)
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.status != null) return error;
      return {body: String(error), status: 500};
    })
    .then(({body, status = 200, type = "text/plain"}) => {
       response.writeHead(status, {"Content-Type": type});
       if (body && body.pipe) body.pipe(response);
       else response.end(body);
    });
}).listen(8000);

async function notAllowed(request) {
  return {
    status: 405,
    body: `Method ${request.method} not allowed.`
  };
}

var {parse} = require("url");
var {resolve, sep} = require("path");

var baseDirectory = process.cwd();

function urlPath(url) {
  let {pathname} = parse(url);
  let path = resolve(decodeURIComponent(pathname).slice(1));
  if (path != baseDirectory &&
      !path.startsWith(baseDirectory + sep)) {
    throw {status: 403, body: "Forbidden"};
  }
  return path;
}
```

And this is the method that is giving me issues:

```
const {mkdir} = require("fs").promises;

methods.MKCOL = async function(request){
  let path = urlPath(request.url);
  /*
  await mkdir(path, {recursive: false}, error =>{
    console.log(error.code);
    if(error.code != "EEXIST") throw error;
    else return {body: "folder already exists",status: 204};
  });
  */
 try{
  await mkdir(path, {recursive: false});
 }catch(error){
  if (error.code != "EEXIST") throw error;
  else return {body: "folder already exists", status: 204};
 }
  return {status: 204};
};
```

What i want this MKCOL method to do when the requested folder exist is to just inform the client that it exist but the way i made it work doesn't do that and just throws the error internally in the server without informing the client, it still does the job of creating the folder when it doesn't exist though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i forgot to add await on on the calls for mkdir and i wrote the recursive object passed to mkdir wrong as well.

```
methods.MKCOL = async function(request){
  let path = urlPath(request.url);

  await mkdir(path, {recursive: false}, error =>{
    console.log(error.code);
    if(error.code != "EEXIST") throw error;
    else return {body: "folder already exists",status: 204};
  });
  return {status: 204};

};
```

now it works well though the message that was sent to the client was not the one that i expected ("folder already exists" from the body passed to the server)